# How can I create multiple databases in Oracle SE1 11.2 rds instance?

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds

I have a Oracle SE1 11.2 instance running. It has one database in it. How can I create another database. I have been using Mysql so far and I am able to create as many databases with it but when tried with Oracle it gives an error.

Comment: what error does it give?

Answer (score 4):

Oracle is different from MySQL in how it terms databases, instances and schemas.

For Oracle each instance has only one database, but each database can have many schemas.

RDS provides only 1 instance(database), if you want many you pay for each instance you want by launching a new instance. However, each instance can support multiple schema's. On RDS you can create up to 30 schema's for Oracle. (see [the RDS FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#2)).

Because each user = a schema, and each schema has its own tables independent of other schema's you can have up to 30 "databases" by leveraging the schema model.